# Java sockets - can't initialise a second connection in the same program life cycle

Tags: java, swing, sockets

I am developing a program that makes use of java sockets. When a button is pressed (either one saying server or client), it calls a method in which initialises a connection, sends and recieves a message and then closes a connection. This works fine the first time around. However, if the connection is closed and then the user wishes to establish another connection by pressing the button, it simply just doesn't work - the connection doesn't establish. Here is the relevent code:

Relevent methods from the class in which allows the users to press the buttons that let them choose to be server or client and then initialises the connection:

```
public static void server() {

    JButton server = new JButton();
    server.setText("Server");

    server.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String name = nameChoice;
            String ip = ipChoice;
            String port = portChoice;
            System.out.println(port);

            try {
                server2(port);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    });

    panel.add(server);

}

public static void client() {

    JButton client = new JButton();
    client.setText("Client");

    client.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String name = nameChoice;
            String ip = ipChoice;
            String port = portChoice;

            try {
                client2(port, ip);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });

    panel.add(client);

}


public static void server2(String port) throws Exception {

    chatWindowScreen gui = new chatWindowScreen();

    gui.frame();

    System.out.println(port);

    network sockets = new network();

    SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker() {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {

            sockets.serverSetup(port);
            sockets.sendMsg("Hi");
            sockets.receiveMsg();
            sockets.closeConnection();

            return null;
        }
    };
    worker.execute();

}

public static void client2(String port, String ip) throws Exception {

    chatWindowScreen gui = new chatWindowScreen();

    gui.frame();

    network sockets = new network();

    SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker() {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {

            sockets.clientSetup(port,ip);
            sockets.receiveMsg();
            sockets.sendMsg("Hi");
            sockets.closeConnection();

            return null;
        }
    };
    worker.execute();

}
```

Class that deals with the sockets and connections:

```
package com.company;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Vector;

public class network {

    static ServerSocket s;
    static Socket s1;
    static OutputStream s1out;
    static DataOutputStream dos;
    static InputStream s1in;

    static chatWindowScreen gui = new chatWindowScreen();

    static String st;

    public static Vector sentVec = new Vector();
    public static Vector receivedVec = new Vector();

    public static Vector messages = new Vector();

    public static void serverSetup(String port) throws IOException {

        System.out.println("Server");
        int portInt = Integer.parseInt(port);
        s = new ServerSocket(portInt);
        s1 = s.accept();
        System.out.println("Server set up");

    }

    public static void clientSetup(String port, String ip) throws IOException {

        System.out.println("Client");
        int portInt = Integer.parseInt(port);
        s1 = new Socket(ip, portInt);
        System.out.println("Client set up");

    }

    public static void closeConnection() throws IOException {

        System.out.println("Closing");
        dos.close();
        s1out.close();
        s1.close();
        System.out.println("Connection closed");

    }

    public static void sendMsg(String message) throws IOException {

        System.out.println("Send MSG");

        s1out = s1.getOutputStream();
        dos = new DataOutputStream(s1out);
        dos.writeUTF(message);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        String t1 = sdf.format(cal.getTime());

        message = t1 + " - " + message;

        sentVec.add(message);
        receivedVec.add("");

        messages.add(message);

        gui.sent.setText("Sent \n");

        for (int i = 0; i < sentVec.size(); i++) {

            gui.sent.append(sentVec.get(i) + "\n");

        }

        gui.received.setText("Received \n");

        for (int i = 0; i < receivedVec.size(); i++) {

            gui.received.append(receivedVec.get(i) + "\n");

        }

        System.out.println("Message sent");

    }

    public static void receiveMsg() throws IOException {

        System.out.println("Receive message");

        s1.setSoTimeout(10000);

        s1in = s1.getInputStream();
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s1in);
        st = (dis.readUTF());


        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        String t1 = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
        st = t1 + " - " + st;

        receivedVec.add(st);
        sentVec.add("");

        messages.add(st);

        gui.received.setText("Received \n");

        for (int i = 0; i < receivedVec.size(); i++) {

            gui.received.append((String) receivedVec.get(i) + "\n");

        }

        gui.sent.setText("Sent \n");

        for (int i = 0; i < sentVec.size(); i++) {

            gui.sent.append((String) sentVec.get(i) + "\n");

        }

        System.out.println("Message received");

    }

    public static Vector getSentVec() {

        return sentVec;

    }

    public static Vector getReceivedVec() {

        return receivedVec;

    }

}
```

I added in some temporary lines of code to see what's happening in the code, and this is what i got when attempting to establish a connection, close it and then open it again:

```
GUI opened
Server
Server set up
Send MSG
Message sent
Receive message
Message received
Closing
Connection closed
GUI opened
Server


GUI opened
Client
Client set up
Receive message
Message received
Send MSG
Message sent
Closing
Connection closed
GUI opened
Client
Client set up
Receive message
```

As you can see from the sequence of events, the server isn't properly initialising a connection the second time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be easier if you supply the thrown exception. It should state something about ports already in use.

Comment: It didn’t give me any exception

Comment: @TheRealJoeWilson, it did throw exception, otherwise you would see "Message received" after "Receive message".

Comment: But the problem isn’t actually with receiving the message, the problem is that the server never gets set up in the first place so it’s waiting to receive somethjng but nothing will be received